How to force a LazyColumn to have the max height rather than using scroll?
In my MainActivity I create this screen:
setContent {
    MyTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
}

That looks like this:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {/* ... */},
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column() {
                Text("Info1")
                Text("Info2")
            }
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                items(users) { user ->
                    Text(user.ane)
                }
            }
        }
    }
)

The problem is that when I have multiple user names displayed in the LazyColumn, I get a scroll. What I want is when I have multiple user names, to expand the list so I can scroll the entire MainScreen and not only the content of the LazyColumn. How to solve this?

You can move whatever should be scrolled with the LazyColumn inside the LazyColumn as well:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    item {
        Column {
            Text("Info1")
            Text("Info2")
        }
    }

    items(users) { user ->
        Text(user.ane)
    }
}

If you use keys for your items you should specify one too for this new item.

It worked for me, thanks.
